# Transfer 200GB from client using Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-iam

I have a client who wishes to transfer 200GB of sensitive data to us.  I would like them to upload this data to a GCloud bucket.

What is the best way to set up an external user to have access to a single new bucket and be able to upload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Through GCP Console try below 2 ways to set up an external user access:**

**1.Your client requires a valid Google Account (Gmail Account):**

1. Go to Console
2. Select Cloud Storage
3. Select Bucket
4. Click on Create (new bucket)
5. After creating a bucket click on the newly created bucket
6. Click on Permissions
7. Click on +Grant access
8. Add the user’s Google Account (Gmail Acocunt)
9. Select Storage Object Creator role.
10. Now the created role grants the permissions to create objects(upload data) into the bucket.

**2. A service account can be used to grant access to resources :**

1. Go to Console
2. Select IAM & Admin
3. Select Service Accounts
4. Click on +Create Service Account
5. Click on the created service account
6. Click on Permissions
7. Service account permission, select a role
8. Select Storage
9. Storage Object Creator Click to continue
10. Click on Create Key
11. Check the JSON button for the key type
12. Save the created JSON file.

Now your service account is created. Make a note of the email address created by Google Cloud which is like `d*****@****-dev.iam.gserviceaccount.com` and the `JSON file credentials`.
For further information go through the GCloud Official documents.

**References :**

1. [IAM basic and predefined roles reference](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#cloud_storage_roles)
2. [Allowing Users to Upload Files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/php/googlestorage/user_upload)